# How to set selected value of DropDownList with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

How do i change the value of the dropdownlist that has its data set via the datasource

```
ddlContacts.DataSource = Data;
ddlContacts.DataBind();
```

I have tried this but does not work:

```
$('#<%= rbDepartment.ClientID %>').change(function() {
    if ($("input[@name=GroupName]:checked").val() == "IS") {
        $('#ddlContactType').val('AM');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
var selectedValue = $("#<%=ddlContacts.ClientID%> option:selected").val();
```

Just noticed that you're trying to set the value:

```
$("#<%=ddlContacts.ClientID%>").val("thevalue");
```

Remember, when dealing with ASP.NET controls on the client side, you have to use the `ClientID`.

Comment: Wouldnt this just get the selected value?

Comment: The "if ($("input[@name=GroupName]:checked").val() == "IS")" is to compare if the selected RadioButton has value "IS"
The value of ddl is to be changed based on the radiobutton

Comment: Note* You also have to worry about the currently selected option first. You will run into a server error if 2 options have selected set to true on a data bound drop down list.

Comment: I'm not 100% positive of this, but I don't think so. Since we're setting the selected value in client script with jQuery, I believe the previously selected item will be deselected as part of that process. I've used this technique before, and I don't recall any server errors ever occurring.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem of getting the current selected value from a drop down list and setting a new value as selected. Below is the code I used and it is working:

**ASP .Net code:**

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlVersion" />
```

**Select the currently selected drop down list option using JQuery:**

```
var selectedVersion = $('#<%=ddlVersion.ClientID%> option:selected').text();
```

**To set the selected value in drop down list:**

```
$('#<%=ddlVersion.ClientID%> option:selected').text(currentVersion);
```

This code is working perfectly fine.